# python iterate over list in range of times and work out average

Tags: python, list, range, average

here is the input csv which the code will be reading taking the team names

```
team_name   half_goals  FT_goals    shots   shots_on_target corners Result
Arsenal 1   1   16  4   4   L
Liverpool   1   1   26  11  12  W
Norwich 0   2   8   2   6   D
Sunderland  0   0   20  3   6   L
Swansea 0   1   17  6   7   L
West Brom   0   0   11  1   4   L
West Ham    1   2   18  4   4   W
Chelsea 2   2   22  5   5   W
Crystal Palace  0   0   5   3   3   L
Man City    2   4   20  11  8   W
Chelsea 1   2   15  3   1   W
Aston Villa 0   0   17  3   8   L
Everton 0   0   22  8   11  D
Fulham  0   1   16  7   1   L
```

here is the code  which l would like to read number times team is mentioned then work out the average

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime 
with open('League.csv','r') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    next(readCSV)
    for row in readCSV:
        #print(row)
         lines = []
         lines.append(row)
         #print (lines)

         teams = set ()

         #print (teams)
         for line in lines :
                 home_team = line[2]
                 teams.add(home_team)

                 #print (teams)
                 for team in teams:
                         match = [line for line in lines if line[2]==team]
                         #print(match)

                         for i in range(5, len(match)):
                                history = match [i-5:i]
                                average = (history / 5)
                                print(average)
```

what l would like to do is to bring an average for every 5 times which team is mentioned in the len of match.

expect output

```
game 1-5 Team one ---  average
game 2-6 Team one ---  average
game 3-7 Team one ---  average
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please first specify input/expected output...

Comment: Thank you and l have done so ...

Answer (score 0):

You are using 4 nested `for loops`, please simplify your code to **one** `for loop` after the other.
    About your question:

> what l would like to do is to bring an average for every 5 times which team is mentioned in the len of match.

Q:*...for every 5 times...*: Please explain in your Question, can't see any team 5 times?
You want the average of the **FT_goals**, per?
Update your *expected output* with real Data from the given csv.